# kubelet service not running on windows worker node

Tags: kubernetes

I need a k8s cluster consisting of linux master node and windows worker node. Although I'm able to set up the master node just fine with v1.26.1 (OS: CentOS 8.x), when I try to run the kubelet service of same version on the windows node (OS: Windows Server 2019), the service goes into a PAUSE state and is not able to run. Has anyone faced such problem before? I must say I'm very new to k8s. Is there something very obvious that I'm missing?

On the windows node i.e. Windows Server 2019 machine, the kubelet service with version 1.15.x runs just fine.